# Google app indexing for iOS and universal links

Tags: ios, google-app-indexing

Does anybody know how google app indexing works for iOS with new implementation via universal links?
As I understand from https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app

> Google App Indexing documentation for iOS 9 serves iOS universal links
>   from Google Search in Safari. App Indexing for iOS versions 7 and 8 is
>   now deprecated and no longer available for new integrations

But indexing mechanism is not clear. How we can add links that can be opened in app to google search?
The only action from app-side is registering of app with:

```
[[GSDAppIndexing sharedInstance] registerApp:your iTunes ID];
```

There are no announcement of app index objects as for Android: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish

So where we can add links for indexing? 
Before iOS 9 custom URL scheme was used to help google engine find site content for iOS apps:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="alternate" href="ios-app://{itunes_id}/{scheme}/{host_path}" />
  ...
</head>
```

Should we still use it for iOS 9?
 Should we use custom scheme
    gsd-{ourscheme} for indexing?

Answer (score 3):

The new integration (from iOS 9) is based on universal links and is using 'http' scheme, so there is no need to use custom gsd-scheme.

There is no need to publish the deep-links using `<link rel>` tags. The deep-links are published via `apple-app-site-association` file.

Follow the steps listed in the official documentation and you should be fine:

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app

Comment: What about the backward compatibility? It seems the new library supports only iOS 9. Google's just deprecated the old libraries supporting iOS 7 as deployment target, what does that mean? Does it mean those library are not maintained anymore or worse even broken? Well that's great.

Comment: Where we have to put apple-app-site-association signed file in Ruby on Rails.I putted it into public folder but not it is not opening in my app.