# universal links with redirects using google url shortener

Tags: ios, url, ios-universal-links, google-url-shortener, google-app-indexing

The use case is, essentially, this:

- the user create some content and uploads it to our server.
- our server responds with the URL.
- the user sends the URL (eg via text message) to another user.
- the other user clicks on the URL. If they have the app installed, they should be taken to the content in the app. If they don't have it, they should still be able to view the content on our site (eg in safari).

This is easy enough, and we have that working, except our URLs are long and we'd like to use shortened URLs. With shortened URLs, the problem is it always opens in Safari, instead of the app, unless we setup a custom domain. (This is described in many places, including here: [iOS Universal Links and URL Shorteners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225871/ios-universal-links-and-url-shorteners)).

The [docs for google URL](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) shortener indicate that they have overcome this somehow:

> Even though App Indexing for iOS is available only in limited release, you can still enable iOS app deep links with goo.gl by implementing App Indexing for iOS. While these deep links may not begin appearing in Search results, they will start working with goo.gl links.

So I installed the app indexing for iOS into our app on a test device and ran it. Then I created a short link but it still opens in my browser, not my app.

Does this really work as advertised? Do I have to wait longer? Install the indexer on more apps? Will a created link open in the app right away, or does the content have to be indexed?

...Or am I missing something else?

Related:

- [Google app indexing for iOS and universal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437925/google-app-indexing-for-ios-and-universal-links)

UPDATE:

The only way I can see this actually working without a custom domain is if Google added every app they indexed to their apple site association file. All I see is google apps there, so obviously that's not the case.

Stack overflow won't let me link it because it thinks it's a link shortener, but it's close to this:

```
https://goo. gl/apple-app-site-association
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exactly right: for this to work, Google would need to add your app to their `apple-app-site-association` file. Unfortunately that would be impossible even if Google *wanted* to do so, because Apple puts a size limit of 128 kb on that file.

Integrating the App Indexing SDK was a good thought, but doesn't solve this issue either.

What you need is a (free) service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). This is specifically designed for exactly what you're trying to accomplish, and takes care of all the housekeeping tasks you are running into. You'll be able to create branded short URLs that take you to your app (if installed) or website fallback (if not installed), and the `AASA` file will be generated automatically for the short URL domain.

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is what I thought, but the docs are misleading. I've looked at Branch, but I didn't see the free option, and shorter URLs weren't really something we wanted to pay for for this particular purpose. I will look again.

Comment: You're welcome! Links are absolutely free with Branch, so this should accomplish what you need